# Pen Only Tablet

Tags: pc, tablet

are there any tablets which do not allow for the user to typing using fingers, only a pen, Because I want to have a tablet running XP where I can use lying down to type word docs and bug test apps.

I normally use an android phone for typing/web browsing, since It is small and can be used with one hand, however the touch keyboard and small screen is not good for typing. (I also have poor eyesight).

I think a hardware keyboard is probably not a good option. XP has two built in 'on screen keyboards' and many third party apps are available.

Comment: XP?  I highly doubt it.